# How to increase the arrow lengths between nodes for DiagrammeR?

Tags: r, diagrammer

supposed I have a diagram like this.

```
library("DiagrammeR")

niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E","X","Y")
from <- c("A","A","A","A","B","C","D","E", "X", "B")
to <- c("B","C","D","E","X","X","Y","Y","Y", "C")
temp <- data.table(from=factor(from, levels=niv),
                   to=factor(to,levels=niv), col=c(rep("blue",5), rep("black",5)))

nodes <-   create_node_df(  n=length(niv), label=niv,  width=0.3) 
edges <- create_edge_df(from = temp$from, to = temp$to, 
                        rel = "leading_to", label=temp$from, color=temp$col
                        ,height  = 25.5  # does nothing
                        , width = 55 # does nothing
                        )   
graph <- create_graph(  nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges)
render_graph(graph)
```

[image]

however what if I want to stretch the nodes way further apart like 2x further?  The reason for this is that sometimes the network gets really large and I don't want all the nodes to bunch up.  I tried changing the height and width as you can see in the above code but that does not seem to do anything. thanks.

edit: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055696/how-to-increase-distance-between-nodes-in-diagrammer-r) but it appears to be outdated and create_edge as well as length does not seem to work anymore.